# What's the best way to reset a char[] in C?

Tags: c, string, overwrite

I use a string:

```
char    word[100];
```

I add some chars to each position starting at 0.
But then I need be able to clear all those positions so that I can start add new characters starting at 0.

If I don't do that then if the second string is shorten then the first one I end up having extra characters from the first string when adding the second one since I don't overwrite them.

Comment: As emerges below, the poster wants to zero out the whole array because he/she doesn't want to use standard library string functions like strcat. He/she wants to be able to just write new chars on top of whatever is there, and count on having a \0 in the next position after he/she stopped writing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to zero out the whole array, you can:

```
memset(word, 0, sizeof(word));
```

Comment: @goe could you show us the entire code - or what it actually outputs after you try this?

Comment: Just want to remind readers that `sizeof(word)` only works as expected when `word` is an array. If `word` is a pointer, then some other way to track the array size is needed.

Answer (score 12):

You don't need to clear them if you are using C-style zero-terminated strings.  You only need to set the element after the final character in the string to NUL ('\0').

For example,

```
char buffer[30] = { 'H', 'i', ' ', 'T', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e', 0 };
// or, similarly:
// char buffer[30] = "Hi There";  // either example will work here.

printf("%s", buffer);
buffer[2] = '\0';
printf("%s", buffer)
```

will output

> Hi There
>   Hi

even though it is still true that `buffer[3] == 'T'`.

Comment: I don't care what it will output, I need to rest all of these positions to ''. How can i do that?

Comment: Are you SURE you need to?  Because what I am saying is that when programming in C, you normally never need to do that.

Answer (score 5):

`strcpy(word,"")` can also be used for this purpose.

Comment: Great simple solution!

Answer (score 1):

You could assign a null terminator to the first position of the `char` array.

```
*word = '\0';
```

Comment: This won't work. When re-filling the array, the \0 gets overwritten and the junk that was there before is still there.

Comment: I mis-understood the problem.  It is not apparent in the OP that the C string handling functions are not being used.